# Node.js throws TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined, even though it works for an other post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, typeerror

So I know there are tons of similar questions out there, and I've read most of them in the past few days. However I didn't find any solution to my problem. The app is about users can post memories(cards) etc... Point is, when I create a new card with POST request, there is no problem, but when I want to sign up a user then all hell breaks loose and throws this error:

> (node:2732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
> at signup (file:///E:/projects/personal/memories-app/backend/controllers/user.controller.js:39:13)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\projects\personal\memories-app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (E:\projects\personal\memories-app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)

I don't know that could be the problem, because other functions work so dunno really.
Here are the codes

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.routes.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/users.routes.js';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello to Memories API');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() =>
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`))
    )
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

user.model.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  id: { type: String },
});

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

the sign up method from user.controller.js

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import User from '../models/user.js';

export const signup = async (res, req) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser)
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exists' });

        if (password !== confirmPassword)
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Passwords don't match" });

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const result = await User.create({
            email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
        });

        const token = jwt.sign(
            { email: result.email, id: result._id },
            'test',
            {
                expiresIn: '1h',
            }
        );

        res.status(200).json({ result, token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong.' });
    }
};
```

and just to see the createPost method (which works) from post.controller.js

```
import PostMessage from '../models/postMessage.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const post = req.body;
    console.log(post);

    const newPost = new PostMessage(post);
    try {
        await newPost.save();

        res.status(201).json(newPost);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

And there is no problem with the front-end because when I simply console.log the req, I can see the body, but if I were to clg the req.body, then it is undefined. I've tried it with postman also, but no luck.

I would appreciate any insight on this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you use to test these? Do you run them from a webpage or e.g. postman? Also please post your router code

Comment: Can you add the form interface from your frontend?

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply, since then @Đăng Khoa Đinh found the bug in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of `res` and `req` in the `signup` function, replace:

```
export const signup = async (res, req) => {
```

by:

```
export const signup = async (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe a spent many days on this!! This is the one, many thanks!!:) Works like it should!

Answer (score 0):

Your User model does not have a firstName, lastName, and confirmPassword types use { name, email, password, } = req.body to sign up a new user.

In your project frontend use
name email, password, confirmPassword to register a use and email, password to log users in.

Comment: I attach the first and last name before saving, but @Đăng Khoa Đinh spotted the problem in my code! Thanks for the reply tho!:)